# Show a div on load using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, loading, wrapper

I have these 2 div's !

```
<div id="loader">
</div>
```

and

```
<div id="wrapper">
</div>
```

"The wrapper div is not inside the loader div for any clarification"

**My script**

```
$(window).bind("load",function() {
           $('#loader').css('display',none);
           $('#wrapper').css('visibility',visible);
        });
```

What I intend to do with the script is to hide the loader div after the page has been completely loaded and display the wrapper div which contains all the contents of the page.
I initially set `display:none` in the wrapper style.

As I expected the loader div is displayed but after the loading has been completed (which I can tell at least from the loading icon of the mouse and the `favicon` region of the browser tab) but the wrapper div is not shown .

Any help would be nice.

Comment: You cannot see your wrapper-div, because you don't change it's `display` style-attribute! Also have a look at http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `$(document).ready()` to load the page completely.

The following code may help you...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loader').css('display','none');
    $('#wrapper').css('display','block');
});
```

Comment: No dude .. Its not helping :/ !
I dont know what am I doing wrong :/

Comment: as you initially set the display of wrapper div is none so you have to use display block in jquery.
I edit the answer. please check

Comment: Yupp !! After I cleared the browser cache this code worked :) Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

Use this;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
           $('#loader').hide();
           $('#wrapper').show();
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
           $('#loader').css('display','none');
           $('#wrapper').css('visibility','visible');
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/33zch/

Comment: Your fiddle seems to be working fine :/ ! but when i use it its not working :/ URGH :/

Comment: Can you put your code to fiddle also? Or which version of jquery do you use?

Answer (score 1):

In some browsers, like Firefox, event `$(window).load()` apperas only after successfully loading  all elements (images, for example), but in Chrome `$(window).load()` and `$(document).ready()` fired in same time. Using `$(window).load()` have potential issue in firefox (maybe in another browsers too): if at least one image on the page is loaded with error then event not occure. And use right syntax:

```
$('#loader').css('display','none');
$('#wrapper').css('display','block');
```

or

```
$('#loader').hide();
$('#wrapper').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this :-

```
$('#loader').css('display','none');
$('#wrapper').css('visibility','visible');
```

Comment: Sorry ? I dont get it ? 
if you meant the way I posted the code, NoobEditor(Thanks man) has edited it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use with this simple way.

```
window.onload = $('#loader').hide();
window.onload = $('#wrapper').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You told that you have initially set `wrapper` element to `display:none;` Then how it will be visible by adding `visibility:visible` ? Instead you should add `display:block` to get this working.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/tUSQ9/)**